# Using TextBox Data from Blend into C# function

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, textbox, blend

I have made a very simple UI in Blend (visual studio 15) which contains a TextBox and a button.

I want the user to insert a number for example 5 into the Textbox and once clicked the button, it will take this int 5 and insert it into a function which do for example ^2 for the input it get.

How can i insert a TextBox data into a different function in my code?

- I would have wrote an example but at this thing im not sure how to write the function that gets the input from TextBox.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

You could hook up an event handler for the `Click` event of the `Button` in your XAML markup (MainWindow.xaml or whatever your file is called):

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1" />
<Button Content="Button" Click="Button_Click" />
```

In the code-behind class (MainWindow.xaml.cs) you could then get the value from the `TextBox` and pass it to any method you want:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int value;
    if (!int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out value))
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid value!");

    MessageBox.Show(value ^ 2);
}
```